# Totally disconnected measurable set with positive measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, connectedness

Could we find a totally disconnected set of the real numbers which is Lebesgue measurable and has positive measure?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. For example the irrational numbers $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 2):

How about the set of irrationals?